# Getting error when Python connects with RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect RabbitMQ from Python. Here is the below code I am using

```
connection = pika.SelectConnection(parameters, self.on_connection_open, self.on_open_error_callback,
                                           stop_ioloop_on_close=False)
```

I setup the configuration in RabbitMQ and copied the same in Python code also. But when running it throws the below error.

*TypeError: _ _init_ _() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stop_ioloop_on_close'*

Can anyone help me to fix this issue. For your information, I am using the latest versions of all the softwares.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, this is an existing code running on a production server.. I am setting this up in my local machine

Comment: Its pika==0.11.2

Comment: yes, this works.. Thanks @Lutz Horn for pointing this

Answer (score 2):

For this issue, need to downgrade pika version to 0.11.2 and the recent versions throwing this error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the argument was [removed](https://github.com/pika/pika/pull/964/commits/bd2580ea9e7d24e6d5199ebf6a77003ddde9f279) in version 1.0.0 because of [this](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/961) issue. You should lock down the requirements to always make sure a version older than 1.0 is installed.

e.g.

Add something like this to the requirements file of your project.

```
pika<1.0
```

In addition it's probably worth looking into having the code fixed, and then removing the version restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to downgrade your version you can just remove the `stop_ioloop_on_close` argument. Since the functionality should have remained the same (i.e. now it's no longer checking what to do on close, so it will keep running).

If you want do want to close the connection you can use the `on_close_callback` parameter to call `connection.ioloop.stop()` yourself if needed.